# Populate a Partial View on page load

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

Im developing an MVC project and im using Ajax for displaying a list of shifts.

Here's my parent page, shifts.chtml:

```
@model UI.ViewModels.ViewModelShiftList

<h2>Shifts</h2>

 @Ajax.ActionLink("View All Shifts", "AllShifts", "Shifts",
                                    new AjaxOptions
                                    {
                                        UpdateTargetId="searchResults",
                                        HttpMethod="GET", //default
                                        InsertionMode= InsertionMode.Replace, //replace
                                        LoadingElementId="progress"
                                    })

   <div id="searchResults">

     @Html.RenderPartial("_ShiftList",model)

    </div>
```

heres the controller action for the above page:

```
public ActionResult Shifts()
    {
        ViewModelShiftList viewModel = new ViewModelShiftList
        {
            Shifts = _shiftService.GetShifts().ToList()
        };
        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

Should I not be able to send the viewmodel produced here into the partial view? Or do I have to create another action for the partial view? If so, what is the correct way to send an action to the controller of a partialview?

The error im gettin is at this point:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("_ShiftList",model)
```

// cannot impilicty convert type void to object

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't seem to work"?  What error are you getting?

Comment: We really could use more data. However, one thing that may not be working is that you *might* need to specify your controller in your "RenderPartial" depending on the context of where it's being used.

Comment: I've updated my post to make it more clear, how do you specifiy what controller and action you want to use for a partial view, I suppose this is my sticking point.

Answer (score 2):

This was a simple fix...I needed to add curly brackets like so..

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("_shiftlist", Model);}
```

Comment: Could also use `@Html.Partial("_shiftlist")`